# Accessing other pages with Twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I've started learning Twig today and wanted to know how I would redirect to another page in my template.

This is my index.php where I also load my homepage.

```
<?php
require '../vendor/autoload.php';
$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('../recourses/views');
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
echo $twig->render('pages/home.twig', array(
    'project_title' => getProjectTitle()
));
```

Now my question is: How could I reach this page with an `<a href="...."></a>` ?
I can't just use `<a href ="pages/home.twig">` since it will show the code instead of the page itself.

I've tried searching but couldn't find my sollution.

Hope anyone can explain this to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I unterstand, you are not using [**Symfony Standard Edition**](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html), but some [**Symfony components**](http://symfony.com/components) + [**Twig**](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) ?

In that case, Twig is only a a templating engine and Symfony functions are missing.

The **path** function (ShinDarth answer) is provided by a twig extension defined in the **Symfony Standard Edition** :

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/twig_reference.html#path

All the **Symfony Standard Edition** function are defined at the same page :

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/twig_reference.html

Using Twig like you do, you can only pass the path as variable and render it as {{ path_variable }}

Comment: Yes, that's right. Any idea of how I can pass it as a variable like that?

Comment: echo $twig->render('pages/home.twig', array(
    'project_title' => getProjectTitle(),'path_variable'=>$path_variable
));

Comment: You must build your url with your own code (may be using the Routing component) ...

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that you have your route named `my_route`,

then via twig you simple do:

```
<a href="{{ path('my_route') }}">Link to my_route</a>
```

Documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#linking-to-pages

Comment: Yup, tried that. That line will give me this error:  Uncaught exception 'Twig_Error_Syntax' with message 'Unknown "path" function in "master.twig"